# Concurrent Dictionary is always empty

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dependency-injection, concurrentdictionary

Whenever I attempt to retrieve a value from a `ConcurrentDictionary` there is no items within the dictionary. Take the following code (shortened to make the question easier to answer):

```cs
public void AddSession(EndPoint remoteEndPoint, IPlayerSession session)
{
    this.logger.LogDebug($"Adding player session to {nameof(WorldContext)}...");

    if (!this.endPointToSessionMap.TryAdd(remoteEndPoint, session))
    {
        this.logger.LogCritical($"The player session could not been added to the {nameof(WorldContext)}!");
    }
}
```

Here, we can see that a *critical* log will be displayed if there was an issue. My log level is set to `Debug` so I should have no issues seeing the log if it occurs.

Now, take note of the following function used to retrieve a player session by it's `remoteEndPoint`:

```cs
public IPlayerSession? FindSessionByRemoteEndPoint(EndPoint remoteEndPoint)
{
    if (!this.endPointToSessionMap.TryGetValue(remoteEndPoint, out var session))
    {
        return null;
    }

    return session;
}
```

This function is then used later on to find a `session` and then remove it. I use the function here like so:

```cs
public void RemoveConnection(EndPoint remoteEndPoint)
{
    this.logger.LogDebug($"Removing TCP client connection from the {nameof(ServerContext)}...");

    // Find the session.
    var session = this.worldContext.FindSessionByRemoteEndPoint(remoteEndPoint);

    // If it's not null, remove it.
    if (session != null)
    {
        // This function is never invoked.
        this.worldContext.RemoveSession(remoteEndPoint);
    }

    if (!this.endPointToConnectionMap.TryRemove(remoteEndPoint, out _))
    {
        this.logger.LogCritical($"The {nameof(ServerContext)} failed to removed a TCP client connection!");
    }
}
```

However, for some reason the `RemoveSession` function is never invoked as `endPointToSessionMap` has no items.

Comment: Are you sure `AddSession` is called on the same "worldContext" object as `RemoveConnection`?

Comment: @KlausGütter yes; `WorldContext` is setup as a singleton using dependency injection.

Comment: Use the Debugger and "Make Object ID" to *verify* that the same object is used. I have had more than one bug where for one reason or another multiple objects where created when there should only be one.

Comment: It seems that Both the the WorldContext and the ...Controller class have an endPointToConnectionMap property. Also try to figure out if there is not something funny going on with the 'singletonness' of the WorldContext object.

Comment: Have you checked that its actually empty or that you just can't find things in the dictionary (As stated before that should be checked via debugging)? For example if Endpoint hasn't a working GetHashcode/Equals implementation this presumably does not work and you dumped your Endpoints in the Dictionary to be never be found again.

Comment: Of what type is Endpoint actually? Is it an IPEndPoint (should work) or an UriEndPoint (should not work).

Comment: Yeah, my money's on `EndPoint` not being a valid key type for a dictionary.

Comment: "Here, we can see that a critical log will be displayed if there was an issue.". No, that's not how `TryAdd` works. `TryAdd` [returns false](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.tryadd?view=net-8.0) when the item was not added, because the key was already present in the dictionary.

Comment: Okay, a few comments to reply too.

@Ralf The dictionary was definitely empty. I used the debugger to determine this. `EndPoint` was a valid type for a dictionary as `GetHashCode` was defined; it is `IPEndPoint`.

@JonasH It actually looked like this was the issue. For some reason, a third party library I was using decided to create a duplicate of my singleton. It's unfortunately an entirely separate problem to be solved in and of it's own.

Anyways; I was _so_ certain that the code should've worked and I'm glad I wasn't going crazy lol.

Comment: @Steven Also; you can see that I was logging a critical log if it couldn't be added ie; if there was an issue.